# Compare IP Address if it is lower than the other one

Tags: c#, .net, comparison, ip-address

Anyone know how to compare 2 ipaddress to see if the ipaddress is lower than the other.

i.e

```
bool b = CurrentIpAddress.IsLowerCompareTo(AnotherIPAddress);
```

I would also like to support both IPV4 and IPV6.

Comment: What do you mean by "lower"?

Comment: -1. There is no commonly accepted ordering of IP ranges, so you have to define your method of comparing in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert each IP address into an integer and do a comparison that way. If you have access to the Extension Methods functionality of the recent .NET Framework then try the following.

```
public static class IPExtensions
{
   public static int ToInteger(this IPAddress IP)
   {
      int result = 0;

      byte[] bytes = IP.GetAddressBytes();
      result = (int)(bytes[0] << 24 | bytes[1] << 16 | bytes[2] << 8 | bytes[3]);

      return result;
   }

   //returns 0 if equal
   //returns 1 if ip1 > ip2
   //returns -1 if ip1 < ip2
   public static int Compare(this IPAddress IP1, IPAddress IP2)
   {
       int ip1 = IP1.ToInteger();
       int ip2 = IP2.ToInteger();
       return (((ip1 - ip2) >> 0x1F) | (int)((uint)(-(ip1 - ip2)) >> 0x1F));
   }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPAddress ip1 = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        IPAddress ip2 = IPAddress.Parse("10.254.254.254");

        if (ip1.Compare(ip2) == 0)
           Console.WriteLine("ip1 == ip2");
        else if (ip1.Compare(ip2) == 1)
           Console.WriteLine("ip1 > ip2");
        else if (ip1.Compare(ip2) == -1)
           Console.WriteLine("ip1 < ip2");
    }
}
```

**EDIT** This does not support IPv6 but can be modified to do so.

Comment: Failed for 255.255.255.255 to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Could you please explain the `Compare` method? At first glance one would think you could just `return ip1.CompareTo(ip2);`. Why doesn't that work?

Answer (score 4):

You can call [IPAddress.GetAddressBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes.aspx) and write a for loop to compare each individual byte.

Answer (score 3):

vane has the right idea but is unfortunately using signed integers. The problem with that is evident in the one comment on his answer. If one of the resulting integers has its most significant bit set, it's interpreted as negative and throws off the comparison.

Here's a modified version (written in Linqpad, so not a complete program) that yields correct results.

```
public static class IpExtensions
{
    public static uint ToUint32(this IPAddress ipAddress)
    {
        var bytes = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();

        return ((uint)(bytes[0] << 24)) |
               ((uint)(bytes[1] << 16)) |
               ((uint)(bytes[2] << 8)) |
               ((uint)(bytes[3]));
    }
}

public static int CompareIpAddresses(IPAddress first, IPAddress second)
{
    var int1 = first.ToUint32();
    var int2 = second.ToUint32();
    if (int1 == int2)
        return 0;
    if (int1 > int2)
        return 1;
    return -1;
}

void Main()
{
    var ip1 = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 255, 255, 255, 255 });
    var ip2 = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    Console.WriteLine(CompareIpAddresses(ip1, ip2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this project for IP address comparison :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26550/Extending-the-IPAddress-object-to-allow-relative-c